# Mysql: How to query records created by all users every day?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

My table has following data:

As you can see above table has user_id and created_at columns. I want to query data as shown below.

I used below query but it only data for 1 user at any date.

e user_id is not null
    GROUP BY DATE(created_at);

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

As you can see, it shows data only for one user a time. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `user_id` in group by clause to get data for each date and each user

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'Requests',
DATE(created_at) AS 'Date',
user_id
FROM ibiza_production.line_write_revenues where user_id is not null
GROUP BY DATE(created_at),user_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'Requests',
DATE(created_at) AS 'Date',user_id
FROM ibiza_production.line_write_revenues where user_id is not null
GROUP BY DATE(created_at), user_id;
```

Comment: You need to add user to group by.

Answer (score 0):

Try to group with concat

```
SELECT `date`,`user_id`,COUNT(*) FROM ibiza_production.line_write_revenues GROUP BY CONCAT(`date`,'-',`user_id`) ORDER BY `date`,`user_id` LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you try this and let me know if it helped you.

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'Requests',
DATE(created_at) AS 'Date',user_id
FROM ibiza_production.line_write_revenues where user_id is not null
GROUP BY DATE(created_at),user_id order by DATE(created_at);
```